# Discrete random variables

Tags: probability

For a discrete random variable $X$ which can take the value $x$, why is the probability that $X = x$ equal to the probability that $X = x^2$?

I have now consulted another textbook and in this second book it said that 
$P(X^2 = x^2) = P(X = x)$.  But I still don't know why this is.  Also I don't know what $X^2$ means.

Comment: do you mean why is the probability that $X = x$ equal to the probability that $X^2 = x^2$?

Comment: If $X$ is a *Bernoulli* random variable (can only take on values $0$ or $1$), then it is true, because $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$. But otherwise it is in general not true.

Comment: what you say is in general not correct, think about throwing a die which can take $X=2$ or $X=4$ and these probabilities are not necessariliy the same if the die is not fair. Could you refine the question?

Comment: Well, the question was, ' A discrete random variable X has a probability distribution x = 1, 2, 3, 4 with respective probabilities 12/25, 6/25, 4/25, 3/25.  Write down the probability distribution for X^2.

Comment: Then the probabilty that $X^2$ is 1 will be 12/25. The probability that $X^2$ is 4 will be 6/25, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a random variable, then $X^2$ is another random variable equal to the square of $X$.  In particular, this means that, if $X = y$ for some number $y$, then $X^2 = y^2$.

Note that, in general, the converse does *not* necessarily hold, since squaring is not a one-to-one mapping.  In particular, if $X^2 = y^2$, then it's possible either that $X = y$ or that $X = -y$.  However, if it's known that $X \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, then the statements $X = y$ and $X^2 = y^2$ are indeed equivalent.

(Note that nothing I wrote above is really specific to random variables: all of it would be just as true if we replaced the random variable $X$ with a simple unknown constant $x$.)

In particular, since (assuming that $X \ge 0$  and $y \ge 0$) the events $X = y$ and $X^2 = y^2$ are the same event, it immediately follows that they must have the same probability.